# Navigation to solutions missing in Dynamics 365 Sales App (trial version)

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have created a trial version of Dynamics 365 sales app. I do not see the navigation menu to reach solutions, to explore created components and modify existing. I have created org from the following link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/sales

I need your help to modify the existing components and to create new solutions, to use it as full Dynamics crm in trial period.

Product has any restrictions to not provide customizations for trial periods?

**Update**: (Solution identified)

Actually my question was not about reaching to solutions, Microsoft provide different trial options when creating trial account for Dynamics crm. you have an option for individual options like only creating sales app, marketing app etc. in these apps there is no option for solution. if we select no customization in creating account then we get full instance of crm and all features and we have solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions area can be found under Settings > Customisations > Solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Dynamic 365 online.
In my case this can be achieved by 2 ways

1. Settings > Solutions
2. Settings > Customization > Solutions

Please refer image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could not find Solutions in the trial version and nothing happened when I tried to enter Solutions from the extension 'Level for Dynamics Crm/365'.

The problem was that the account I created for the trial version was not an admin.

1. Settings -> Security -> Users
2. Promote your user to admin